# exception image not found

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm creating a script to identify an image and perform some actions, basically when I find the image as an action, when I can not find, another.
but when the image is not found the pyautogui itself already returns error and closes the function. returning the following error: ImageNotFoundExeption ('Could not locate the image ....')
I basically need it to work if else

```py
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:

        def locate_img(img):
            locate = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)

            if locate:
                X,Y = pyautogui.center(locate)                              
                pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y, 0.2)

            else:
                X,Y = pyautogui.center(locate)                              
                pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y, 0.2)  


        locate_img(find)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

when the image is not located already returns a direct error in locate, nor even goes to the else

Comment: Where's `find` defined? I don't quite understand the problem. Your `if`/`else` is completely redundant. The image probably is not on the screen.

Comment: The error is due to, you are not properly handling exception. You are only handling KeyboardInterrupt Exception. You have to handle the exception properly.

Comment: @connectyourcharger the find I'm pointing to an image in the root directory, I put the else wrong, it's to display an image message not found

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would want to have the actual part which throws the error in a try except block rather than the whole thing.

```
while True:

    def locate_img(img):

        try:
             locate = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
             locate = None

        if locate:
            X,Y = pyautogui.center(locate)                              
            pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y, 0.2)

        else:
            X,Y = pyautogui.center(locate)                              
            pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y, 0.2)  


    locate_img(find)
```

Comment: I tried this way more continues returning the error, just a correction, in the else is to display an image message not found